# How to display String name of task category in event log using Write-EventLog?

Tags: windows, events, powershell, logging

So, I am attempting to write to the Windows Event Log using `Write-EventLog`.  I've compiled a CategoryMessageFile .dll and have registered it in the registry.

My script writes to the event log for the most part, but the problem is that the event doesn't display the category name; it displays the category message id enumerated in the dll.

```
New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source 'test1' -CategoryResourceFile 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\test.dll'

Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source 'test1' -EntryType Information -EventId 1 -Message "$($DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[$i][6])" -Category 1
```

I know the mapping is correct because when I run

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Newest 3 | Format-List
```

The correct Category name shows up under Category for the events I had just written to the log.

Here is what my mc file looked like.

```
;// Header


;// Categories
MessageIdTypedef=WORD

MessageId=0x1
Language=English
ETLUncategorizedError
.

MessageId=0x2
Language=English
ETLThresholdExceeded
.

MessageId=0x3
Language=English
ETLMalformattedFile
.

MessageId=0x4
Language=English
ETLWebInvocationFailure
.
```

So, how do I get the name to display instead of the number in the event log?

Comment: Working the backlog here 2 years later :P Did you solve it? The category was visible in the PowerShell but not in the Event Viewer (GUI)? If so, did you try restarting Event Viewer (or the computer for that matter) after you registered the category message file? "Note that when you have registered a category message file, you have to restart the event log viewer to pick up the changes." (Source: http://www.drdobbs.com/customizing-event-log-categories/184405714)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for it in the Application or System log event and the first command you ran created a log named TEST1.

DESCRIPTION
    This cmdlet creates a new classic event log on a local or remote computer. It can also register an event source that writes to the new log or to an
    existing log.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the machine's `Authenticated Users` or `Users` group to the message folder's security level. Keep the default permissions. Then either reboot or try to restart the EventLog service.

At an administrator command prompt: `net stop eventlog`

You will likely be prompted to shutdown other services. You must enter `Y` to continue. The services being shutdown will normally restart on their own so you just need to wait a few seconds. The eventlog service may fail to shutdown because another service has restarted, it may take a couple of tries to get everything down. Watch the resulting text closely for status.